# Count the Subarray's which has bitwise and of its elements equal to Zero

Tags: python, list, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Suppose we have a list of numbers

```
[7,2,9,8,6,12,109,28,14,19]
```

I want to find a efficient way to count the all sub-list of this list which will have bitwise and equal to zero

like:

```
[2,5] # 2&5 = 0
[9,5,7,2] # 9&5&7&2 = 0
```

Let me know if anyone know how to do it most efficiently

Comment: Kinda hard to give you a hint if you don't provide your own attempt... As a hint a naive solution would run in O(N^2) and a fast solution, O(N), where N is the number of elements in your list.

Comment: Well I know the naive way its to just get all the sublists and the perform bitwise and on all the elements of the sub-list

Comment: You example is confusing as the original list does not contain a `5`.

Comment: While you should still post your existing solutions and research for stackoverflow questions, it's possibly understandable here, since google searches for 'counting bitwise and of subarrays' actually turn up next to nothing. As a hint for the `O(n)` solution: Can you solve this in linear time if all entries are 0 or 1? How about when all entries are 0-3 (i.e. only two bits to consider)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in `O(n)` time using a sliding window.

If we know that a subarray of `A` on indices `[L, R]` has an `&` of zero, then we know that all larger subarrays (`[L, R + 1]`, `[L, R + 2]`, `[L, R + 3]`, ...) will also have an `&` of  zero due to **monotonicity of `&` under inclusion**.

For example, computing the partial `&` products of an array from the left:

```
Array (Base 10): [  7,  3,   10,   5]

Array (Binary) : [111, 11, 1010, 101]

Partial &s     : [111, 11,   10,   0]
```

---

We'll iterate over the `right` end of our sliding window, while storing the smallest `left` end (i.e. the largest window) such that `A[left, left + 1, ... right]` has a nonzero bitwise `&`. Note that this `left` end can only ever increase as the right end increases.

To update our window, we'll need to

1. Be able to take an `&` of our window with `A[right]` (easy)
2. Be able to remove the `&` of `A[left]` from our window (hard)

To do removals efficiently, we'll instead **track the count of set-bits for all elements in our window at each bit position**. This lets us add and remove elements from our window, and test whether the `&` of our window is zero by testing whether each set bit position has a count less than the length of the window.

Here's a walkthrough of the maximal nonzero windows on an example array:

```
Base 10:
A = [7, 2, 9, 8, 6, 12, 109, 28, 14, 19]

Binary:
111, 10, 1001, 1000, 110, 1100, 1101101, 11100, 1110, 10011


Maximal nonzero [windows] at each right endpoint:


--------------------------------------------------------------
[111], 10, 1001, 1000, 110, 1100, 1101101, 11100, 1110, 10011
^   ^

left = 0, right = 0, size = 1



--------------------------------------------------------------
[111, 10], 1001, 1000, 110, 1100, 1101101, 11100, 1110, 10011
^       ^

left = 0, right = 1, size = 2



--------------------------------------------------------------
111, 10, [1001], 1000, 110, 1100, 1101101, 11100, 1110, 10011
         ^    ^                                         

left = 2, right = 2, size = 1



--------------------------------------------------------------
111, 10, [1001, 1000], 110, 1100, 1101101, 11100, 1110, 10011
         ^          ^                                         

left = 2, right = 3, size = 2



--------------------------------------------------------------
111, 10, 1001, 1000, [110], 1100, 1101101, 11100, 1110, 10011
                     ^   ^

left = 4, right = 4, size = 1



--------------------------------------------------------------
111, 10, 1001, 1000, [110, 1100], 1101101, 11100, 1110, 10011
                     ^         ^

left = 4, right = 5, size = 2



--------------------------------------------------------------
111, 10, 1001, 1000, [110, 1100, 1101101], 11100, 1110, 10011
                     ^                  ^

left = 4, right = 6, size = 3



--------------------------------------------------------------
111, 10, 1001, 1000, [110, 1100, 1101101, 11100], 1110, 10011
                     ^                         ^

left = 4, right = 7, size = 4



--------------------------------------------------------------
111, 10, 1001, 1000, [110, 1100, 1101101, 11100, 1110], 10011
                     ^                               ^   

left = 4, right = 8, size = 5



--------------------------------------------------------------
111, 10, 1001, 1000, 110, 1100, 1101101, 11100, [1110, 10011]
                                                ^           ^   

left = 8, right = 9, size = 2
```

Here, the sum of nonzero-`&` window sizes is `23`. As a length `10` array has `55` possible subarrays, the answer is `55 - 23 = 32` bitwise-`&`-zero subarrays.

Python code:

```py
def count_bitwise_and_zero(nums: List[int]) -> int:
    """Count nonempty subarrays with & of elements equal to 0.
    Given a list on nonnegative integers,
    returns the number of contiguous, nonempty subarrays for which the
    bitwise and of all elements in the subarray are equal to 0.

    Runs in linear time on fixed-width integers.
    """

    def get_set_bit_indices(x: int) -> List[int]:
        """Return indices of set bits in x"""
        pow_2 = 1
        exponent = 0
        set_bits = []

        while pow_2 <= x:
            if pow_2 & x != 0:
                set_bits.append(exponent)

            exponent += 1
            pow_2 *= 2

        return set_bits

    def is_bitwise_and_zero(window_length: int, bit_counts: Dict[int, int]) -> bool:
        """Given bit counts for a window of an array, return whether the
        window's elements have bitwise AND equal to zero."""
        return all(value < window_length for value in bit_counts.values())

    n = len(nums)
    total_subarray_count = n * (n + 1) // 2

    nonzero_subarray_count = 0
    window_bit_counts = Counter()

    """At every iteration start, [left_idx, right_idx] is the longest subarray
    ending at right_idx whose bitwise AND is nonzero."""
    left_idx = 0

    for right_idx, right_element in enumerate(nums):
        if right_element == 0:
            window_bit_counts.clear()
            left_idx = right_idx + 1
            continue

        # Expand window to include right
        window_bit_counts += Counter(get_set_bit_indices(right_element))

        # Shrink window until AND is nonzero
        while (left_idx < right_idx
               and is_bitwise_and_zero(right_idx - left_idx + 1, window_bit_counts)):

            window_bit_counts -= Counter(get_set_bit_indices(nums[left_idx]))
            left_idx += 1

        nonzero_subarray_count += (right_idx - left_idx + 1)

    return total_subarray_count - nonzero_subarray_count
```

Example usage:

```py
count_bitwise_and_zero([7, 2, 9, 8, 6, 12, 109, 28, 14, 19])
>>> 32
```

N.B. There's an assumption that the maximum bit-width of the integers is constant. To get a linear-time solution when integers can be arbitrarily large, you'll need to keep a meta-counter, which tracks counts of counts of set bits.

As an exercise, you can try to generalize to the problem of bitwise `&` equal to some target `t` which may be greater than zero; it takes a bit more work.

Comment: The Solution passed 9 test cases and failed 1 Time limit exceeded I don't think the solution code works in O(n) but It is efficient and Also Can you Please Explain the is_bitwise_and_zero function working I understood the rest of code not sure how that is working

Comment: @BhaveshPurohit Can you share the problem source? That function determines whether a subarray (aka window) of length `L` has bitwise `&` equal to zero. This happens exactly when the bit-counts for each bit-position are all less than `L`. This is equivalent to there being no shared set-bit-position among all of the integers in the window

Comment: @BhaveshPurohit Can you share the constraints? I'm fairly certain it's linear, but there's a constant factor of `32` or `64` depending on the input bit-size. It's also possible to use integer arrays instead of dictionaries if you know the bit-count, which should be much faster.

Comment: The problem is from a challenge I can't open it again I just shared As much as I can remember

Comment: The Failed case was hidden so I don't have the input set for that

Comment: @BhaveshPurohit That's harder to fix then, but optimizations are still possible. You maybe should have mentioned in the question that it's from a coding challenge, especially if it's active.